# Hazelcast Client Server connection details

Tags: hazelcast

I have setup a 2 node hazelcast cluster on Amazon EC2. On one of the nodes I have a client program which connects to the cluster and runs a atomiclong counter increment&get operation.

How can I find out to which Hazelcast server node did the client connect and run the incrementAndGet operation ?

Thanks

Comment: Which Hazelcast version are you using. So are you using 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: Hazelcast version 3.1.3

Answer (score 1):

An AtomicLong is owned by a single partition and a partition is owned by a single member.

In Hazelcast 3, a client knows about which member owns which partitions, so it will automatically forward a call on an AtomicLong to the right machine.

[edit]
Why do you need to know?

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned I have a 2 node hazelcast cluster and on each of these nodes I have a client running. I wanted to know if the client is connecting to the local hazelcast server or to the remote hazelcast server. How to enable detailed logging on the hazelcastclient to find out which hazelcast server the client is sending out the requests too ?

Comment: The client will automatically be connected to all members; once it has connected to one, it will be updated continuously with member/partition information.

Comment: I am running my hazelcast server and client in one EC2 instance. This instance is autoscaled, so I have many clients and servers. I am currently using cluster.addMembershipListener and on memberAdded and memberRemoved methods I am re-initializing the ClientConfig and HazelcastClient with the IPs of the hazelcast servers. Do you mean to say there's no need to initialize the ClientConfig & HazelcastClient. I did this because if the local hazelcast server fails the client will be able to connect to other hazelcast servers in the cluster.  Let me know.  - Thanks

Comment: As long as the client is able to connect to one, it will know about all. So you don't need to configure all cluster members for the client; just enough to make sure that your client is able to connect to at least one of them. Once the connection is made to one of the members, it will automatically learn about ALL members in your cluster.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, mark the answer as up please so that people don't need to provide additional answers.

Comment: Does the client connect to the local instance of the server by default ? And if the local hazelcast server is not reachable it will failover to a different hazelcast server. This is to make sure that the latency between the client and server is minimal. I am looking into this because my client and server will be spread across zones.

Comment: The client will connect to all members in the cluster. If the call is for a particular machine (e.g. a map.put or an atomiclong.get), it will immediately be send to the machine owning that partition. If it doesn't matter which machine is used, it will use round robin policy but this is configurable.

If a machine is not reachable, it will automatically failover to the  new partition owner. 

So you don't have control on calls meant for a particular machine (most of your calls will be like this). Only for the other calls you could plug in your own load balancer which relies on minimal latencies

Comment: can we ensure by default the hazelcast client calls will be sent to hazelcast server running localhost. If the hazelcast server running on localhost is crashed then the client can reach out to others. We are using only atomiclong (get&Increment). - Thx

Comment: An IAtomicLong is stored in a specific partition, so all calls to that atomiclong, will be send to that partition. It would be pointless to send these calls to localhost, because who says that the localhost owns that particular partition.

There is an option to let the client not use smart routing (ClientConfig.smartRouting) so that it doesn't know about the partitions. And then you should configure the client not to use round robin. 

But imho this is not a solution. I have the impression that you are missing the part of a AtomicLong being part of a partition.

Comment: Worth mentioning that there is something called Client Unisocket mode, which if enabled will ensure that client will communicate with the cluster through a single node: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.0/clients/java#java-client-operation-modes . Not sure what happens if that node goes down though.

Comment: @IvanR It will failover to a different node.